# How to modify color brightness in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, colors, rgb, hsl

In c#, you can get the HSL brightness of a color by doing Color.GetBrightness(). If I want to increase the brightness of a color by a certain percentage, I cannot simply multiply the individual RGB values by that amount. It seems HSL doesn't work like that. How would I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I adjust the brightness of a color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737217/how-do-i-adjust-the-brightness-of-a-color)

Answer (score 2):

I think this article can help you with this and all other color related questions. It has C# source for all conversions and modifications.

[RGB and HSL Colour Space Conversions](http://web.archive.org/web/20110425154034/http://www.bobpowell.net/RGBHSB.htm)