# JAVASCRIPT brightness function - decrease

Tags: javascript, jquery, hex, brightness

i founded this piece of code here on stack:

```
function increase_brightness(hex, percent){
    var r = parseInt(hex.substr(1, 2), 16),
        g = parseInt(hex.substr(3, 2), 16),
        b = parseInt(hex.substr(5, 2), 16);

    return '#' +
       ((0|(1<<8) + r + (256 - r) * percent / 100).toString(16)).substr(1) +
       ((0|(1<<8) + g + (256 - g) * percent / 100).toString(16)).substr(1) +
       ((0|(1<<8) + b + (256 - b) * percent / 100).toString(16)).substr(1);
}
```

does anyone knows how to make the exactly inverse?

function `decreas_brightness(){}` i mean

Comment: The function is not works at all cases. `increase_brightness('#777777', 100)`: output is #000000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is from [JavaScript Calculate brighter colour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443990/javascript-calculate-brighter-colour). According to the comments, the following change should make it decrease brightness:

```
function decrease_brightness(hex, percent){
    var r = parseInt(hex.substr(1, 2), 16),
        g = parseInt(hex.substr(3, 2), 16),
        b = parseInt(hex.substr(5, 2), 16);

   return '#' +
       ((0|(1<<8) + r * (100 - percent) / 100).toString(16)).substr(1) +
       ((0|(1<<8) + g * (100 - percent) / 100).toString(16)).substr(1) +
       ((0|(1<<8) + b * (100 - percent) / 100).toString(16)).substr(1);
}
```

Comment: What purpose does your static (1 << 8) serve? Why not just enter the corresponding value?

Comment: This was actually discussed by the author of this code in the comments of the original question - see his explanation in the link for the full explanation, but essentially it's so that the result will be formatted correctly (eg, '05' rather than '5')