# Javascript Calculate darker colour

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors, calculator

how can i change this calculation to a darker and not brighter color?

```
function increase_brightness(hex, percent){
    // strip the leading # if it's there
    hex = hex.replace(/^\s*#|\s*$/g, '');

    // convert 3 char codes --> 6, e.g. `E0F` --> `EE00FF`
    if(hex.length == 3){
        hex = hex.replace(/(.)/g, '$1$1');
    }

    var r = parseInt(hex.substr(0, 2), 16),
        g = parseInt(hex.substr(2, 2), 16),
        b = parseInt(hex.substr(4, 2), 16);

    return '#' +
       ((0|(1<<8) + r + (256 - r) * percent / 100).toString(16)).substr(1) +
       ((0|(1<<8) + g + (256 - g) * percent / 100).toString(16)).substr(1) +
       ((0|(1<<8) + b + (256 - b) * percent / 100).toString(16)).substr(1);
}
```

**src** = [JavaScript Calculate brighter colour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443990/javascript-calculate-brighter-colour)

**demo** http://jsbin.com/utavax/3/edit

Comment: did you try with a negative percent ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change

```
return '#' +
   ((0|(1<<8) + r + (256 - r) * percent / 100).toString(16)).substr(1) +
   ((0|(1<<8) + g + (256 - g) * percent / 100).toString(16)).substr(1) +
   ((0|(1<<8) + b + (256 - b) * percent / 100).toString(16)).substr(1);
```

to

```
return '#' +
   ((0|(1<<8) + r * (1 - percent / 100)).toString(16)).substr(1) +
   ((0|(1<<8) + g * (1 - percent / 100)).toString(16)).substr(1) +
   ((0|(1<<8) + b * (1 - percent / 100).toString(16)).substr(1);
```

will fix your problem. [demo](http://jsbin.com/utavax/7/).

But darker color is not a good definition. Darker can be interpreted as less brightness or less saturation. So the better approach is to convert the RGB color space to HSB color space, and tweak the S/B channels, then convert them back.

---

A little explanation on why negative value to original code is not OK.

Give -100 as percent, and some channel, say r, less than 128. Then

```
r + (256 - r) * percent / 100
```

is less than 0, after plus `1 << 8` = 256

```
((0|(1<<8) + r + (256 - r) * percent / 100)
```

is less than 256.

Take a number less than 256 will generate at most two hex digits by calling `toString(16)`, so `.substr(1)` will contain 0 or 1 digit only. By combining all these wrong digits together will not generate a proper color in hex representation.

Answer (score 4):

I updated your original function to do a cheap version of lightening/darkening by basically multiplying a percentage (up or down) off the original RGB values.

```js
function adjust(hexInput: string, percent: number) {
    let hex = hexInput;

    // strip the leading # if it's there
    hex = hex.replace(/^\s*#|\s*$/g, "");

    // convert 3 char codes --> 6, e.g. `E0F` --> `EE00FF`
    if (hex.length === 3) {
        hex = hex.replace(/(.)/g, "$1$1");
    }

    let r = parseInt(hex.substr(0, 2), 16);
    let g = parseInt(hex.substr(2, 2), 16);
    let b = parseInt(hex.substr(4, 2), 16);

    const calculatedPercent = (100 + percent) / 100;

    r = Math.round(Math.min(255, Math.max(0, r * calculatedPercent)));
    g = Math.round(Math.min(255, Math.max(0, g * calculatedPercent)));
    b = Math.round(Math.min(255, Math.max(0, b * calculatedPercent)));

    return `#${r.toString(16).toUpperCase()}${g.toString(16).toUpperCase()}${b
        .toString(16)
        .toUpperCase()}`;
}

console.log(adjust("#49D174", -14)) // Darken by 14% = #3FB464 
console.log(adjust("#49D174", -27)) // Darken by 27% = #359955
```

The function takes the percent as an integer, but could easily be modified for a decimal. Negative to darken, positive to lighten.

Answer (score 0):

I've taken the main idea from [Stylus](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/) ([1](https://github.com/LearnBoost/stylus/blob/master/lib/functions/index.styl#L130), [2](https://github.com/LearnBoost/stylus/blob/master/lib/functions/index.js#L815)) and a few code parts from [Stack Overflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9493060/330471) and produced a library, [darken_color.js](https://github.com/shybovycha/darken_color.js).

Here are a few usage examples:

```
darken('lightgreen', '0.1'); // -> #63e763 
darken('lightgreen', '10'); // -> #63e763
darken('#90EE90', '10'); // -> #63e763
darken('#9e9', '10%'); // ->  #98ed98
```

Answer (score -1):

```
return '#' +
   ((0|(1<<8) + r + (256 - r) * percent / 100).toString(16)).substr(1) +
   ((0|(1<<8) + g + (256 - g) * percent / 100).toString(16)).substr(1) +
   ((0|(1<<8) + b + (256 - b) * percent / 100).toString(16)).substr(1);
```

Here you are adding some percentage of `r`, `g` and `b` to current values which makes the color lighter. If you use a negative value for percentage, it will decrease from current values and make the color darker.

Comment: give -100 as percent, and some channel < 128. Then that channel's value is less than 256 after plus 1<<8, and the `toString()` result is no longer 3 chars long, so the color is not valid. That's why negative value is not ok.