# Brighten Color in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

To have brighten color in highcharts, I must write only in this way? :

```
color: {
  linearGradient: [0,500,0,750],
  stops: [
    [0,Highcharts.Color('#E60028').brighten(0.1).get('rgb')],
    [1,Highcharts.Color('#5A000A').brighten(0.1).get('rgb')]  
    ]               
},
```

or is there another way?

For example:

```
color: {
  linearGradient: [0,500,0,750],
  stops: [
    [0,('#E60028').brighten(0.1).get('rgb')],
    [1,('#5A000A').brighten(0.1).get('rgb')]  
    ]               
},
```

I would like to know if is important to put `Highcharts.Color`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Highcharts.Color** is a function which given the color code, gives you an object. That object contains the **brighten** function you are using. So yes it is important, unless you write your own function which does something like that.

It actually gives you the **`rgb(xx,yy,zz)`** version with the brightness involved. I don't know any other well known function or method which does this, so I recommend you keep using it.

Look at these questions and you'll see it's not an easy task changing the brightness:

1. [JavaScript Calculate brighter colour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443990/javascript-calculate-brighter-colour)
2. [Increase CSS brightness color on click with jquery/javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833624/increase-css-brightness-color-on-click-with-jquery-javascript)

Comment: why is Highcharts.color is not documented on their class reference page?

Answer (score 0):

The **Highcarts.Color()** accepts **rgb()** and **rgba()** values but not plain HTML/CSS-Color codes. Put the parameter in quotes.

```
color: {
  linearGradient: [0,500,0,750],
  stops: [
    [0,Highcharts.Color('rgb(230, 0, 40)').brighten(0.1).get('rgb')],
    [1,Highcharts.Color('rgb( 90, 0, 10)').brighten(0.1).get('rgb')]  
    ]               
},
```