# c# - Increase Hex colour by xx%

Tags: c#

I allow my users to set a background colour in their app (ie #D900D9), which is stored as a string.
I then would like to set a property, 'border' which will take the hex value 'background' and  the darkness say by 20%?( ie #770077)
How can I achieve this?

```
public string backgroundColor { get; set; }
 public string borderColor
        {
            get
            {
                return backgroundColor + 20%
            } 
        }
```

Comment: nope, I just dont where to start, lots of RGB examples, just wondering if something simple existed out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public string backgroundColor { get; set; } 
public string borderColor
        {
get
            {
                Color c1 = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(backgroundColor);
                Color c2 = Color.FromArgb(c1.A,(int)(c1.R * 0.8), (int)(c1.G * 0.8), (int)(c1.B * 0.8));
                return System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToHtml(c2);
            } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to create a Color object

```
var yourColor = Color.FromHex(backgroundColor);
```

And then just factor the RGB values:

```
var c2 = Color.FromArgb(yourColor.A,
    (int)(yourColor.R * 0.8), (int)(yourColor .G * 0.8), (int)(yourColor.B * 0.8));
```

(which should darken it; or, for example, * 1.25 to brighten it)

Credits: [How do I adjust the brightness of a color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737217/how-do-i-adjust-the-brightness-of-a-color) (@Marc Gravell)